# block in windows_hyperv_admin Error when trying vagrant up

Tags: vagrant

I'm using Vagrant for my environment and I've got a little issue shown below.

```
kk@Lenovo MINGW64 ~/sravz/vm1
$ vagrant up
C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.4/lib/vagrant/util/platform.rb:85:in `block in windows_hyperv_admin?': undefined method `include?' for #<Vagrant::Util::Subprocess::Result:0x2634e88> (NoMethodError)
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.4/lib/vagrant/util/platform.rb:89:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.4/lib/vagrant/util/platform.rb:89:in `windows_hyperv_admin?'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.4/plugins/providers/hyperv/provider.rb:20:in `usable?'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.4/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:381:in `block in default_provider'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.4/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:379:in `each'
```

I have initialised my project with vagrant init but for some reason vagrant up refuses to work.

Comment: can you give the list of the plugin 'vagrant plugin list` and the Vagrantfile you're using

Comment: @Frederic Henri 
These are the plugins which i have installed                                                                                                    
vagrant-managed-servers (0.7.1)
vagrant-multi-putty (1.5.0)
vagrant-share (1.1.5, system)
vagrant-vbguest(0.12.0)        
                                                                                 
minimal vagrantfile:
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue, and as @Frédéric Henri mentioned, this is related with this issue: https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/7465.

I just followed the suggestion made in one of the comments and now is working fine :)

> *I had the same issue (initially thought it was because of Hyper-V, which I already uninstalled and the errors remained). But if you installed Virtualbox today, the issue is probably because 5.1 has just been released a few hours ago (creating an environment variable VAGRANT_DEFAULT_PROVIDER set to "virtualbox" shows a message that says it only supports up to 5.0).*
>
> ***Uninstall 5.1, and install Virtualbox 5.0.x instead until that issue is closed, that fixed it for me.**

You can find the older releases [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Download_Old_Builds). For 5.0.x. specifically, [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Download_Old_Builds_5_0).

Answer (score 2):

you might have hit https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/7465

Basically you need to make sure [virtualbox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) is installed on your machine.