# 'vagrant up' not working on Windows

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, virtualbox, git-bash, vagrant-windows

I am trying to use Vagrant via Git Bash to download the Linux OS and start up the virtual machine on Windows 7. I have already run the command `vagrant init hashicorp/precise32` which places the 'vagrantfile' in the destination folder.

The problem starts when I run the command `vagrant up`. I get the following on the Git Bash :

```
C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.4/lib/vagrant/util/platform.rb:85:in `block in windows_hyperv_admin?': undefined method `include?' for #<Vagrant::Util::Subprocess::Result:0x28c68f0> (NoMethodError)
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.4/lib/vagrant/util/platform.rb:89:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.4/lib/vagrant/util/platform.rb:89:in `windows_hyperv_admin?'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.4/plugins/providers/hyperv/provider.rb:20:in `usable?'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.4/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:381:in `block in default_provider'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.4/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:379:in `each'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.4/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:379:in `default_provider'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.4/lib/vagrant/plugin/v2/command.rb:174:in `block in with_target_vms'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.4/lib/vagrant/plugin/v2/command.rb:201:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.4/lib/vagrant/plugin/v2/command.rb:201:in `block in with_target_vms'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.4/lib/vagrant/plugin/v2/command.rb:183:in `each'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.4/lib/vagrant/plugin/v2/command.rb:183:in `with_target_vms'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.4/plugins/commands/up/command.rb:131:in `install_providers'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.4/plugins/commands/up/command.rb:85:in `execute'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.4/lib/vagrant/cli.rb:42:in `execute'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.4/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:302:in `cli'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.4/bin/vagrant:174:in `<main>'
```

Please help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have virtualbox installed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [block in windows\_hyperv\_admin Error when trying vagrant up](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38181341/block-in-windows-hyperv-admin-error-when-trying-vagrant-up)

Comment: Yes..I have VirtualBox installed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I had the same problem on `Windows10` with `Vagrant 1.8.4` and `Virtualbox 5.1.0`. After uninstall of VirtualBox and reinstall version `5.0.24` it works.